# Filter out rows in a DataSet based on unique ID and distinct child parameter

Tags: c#, sql, .net, filter, dataset

I have a **DataSet** dsInvoiceData that contains the fields "ACTIVITY", "LOGUID", "VALUE".

**Example** of problem Dataset:

```
ACTIVITY-----LOGUID-----VALUE
```

---

```
MOVE  ------- AAAAAA ----- 000000

STORE ------- AAAAAA ----- 111111

STORE ------- AAAAAA ----- 222222

STORE ------- AAAAAA ----- 333333

MOVE  ------- BBBBBB ----- 000000

STORE ------- BBBBBB ----- 222222
```

---

**How can I create a new DATASET (from the current one)?**

which only contains rows:

`(WHERE VALUE = 000000)`

OR

`(IF (VALUE != 000000) AND (each LOGUID can only have DISTINCT ACTIVITY))`

**Example** of Result, Dataset should be:

```
ACTIVITY-----LOGUID-----VALUE
```

---

```
MOVE  ------- AAAAAA ----- 000000

STORE ------- AAAAAA ----- 111111

MOVE  ------- BBBBBB ----- 000000

STORE ------- BBBBBB ----- 222222
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get this done: (not sure if there are better ways to do this, if so please do tell)

**First create a new DataSet with same columns (.Copy) as the original but remove the rows (.Clear)**

```
DataSet dsInvoiceDataFiltered = new DataSet();
            DataTable dtInvoiceDataFiltered = dsInvoiceData.Tables[0].Copy();
            dtInvoiceDataFiltered.Clear();
```

**Second create a DataTable to hold the LOGUID entries in dtInvoiceDataFiltered where VALUE !=0**

```
DataTable dtDistinctActivityPerLogUid = new DataTable("DistinctActivityPerLogUid");
           dtDistinctActivityPerLogUid.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Activity", typeof(string)));
           dtDistinctActivityPerLogUid.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Loguid", typeof(int)));
```

**Then apply filter logic on the original DataSet**

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsInvoiceData.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            int iVALUE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["VALUE"]);
            int iLogUid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LOGUID"]);
            string sActivity = Convert.ToString(dr["ACTIVITY"]);

            // This is a unique situation (MOVE) 
            // and must be added to the new dataset
            if (VALUE == 0)
            {
                dtInvoiceDataFiltered.ImportRow(dr);
            }
            else
            {
                // This is a STORE/OTHER LOGUID with multiple VALUES 
                // only 1 of them should be added to the new list

                // Check if there is already a VALUE != 0 for that LOGUID
                DataRow[] drRowsThatMatchLogUID = dtDistinctActivityPerLogUid.Select("Loguid = '" + iLogUid + "' AND Activity = '" + sActivity + "' ");
                if (drRowsThatMatchLogUID.Length == 0)
                {
                    // If there isn't one in yet, add 1 to the new list 
                    // and to the Datatable to keep track of LOGUID entries
                    dtInvoiceDataFiltered.ImportRow(dr);

                    DataRow drNewLogUID = dtDistinctActivityPerLogUid.NewRow();
                    drNewLogUID["Activity"] = sActivity;
                    drNewLogUID["Loguid"] = iLogUid;
                    dtDistinctActivityPerLogUid.Rows.Add(drNewLogUID);
                }                   
            }
        }
        // dsInvoiceDataFiltered is now the DataSet that contains the filtered solution
        dsInvoiceDataFiltered.Tables.Add(dtInvoiceDataFiltered);
```

**PS:Not using linq since I have to work in .Net 2.0**

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the DefaultView property, and filter the datatable

```
var t = new DataSet();
t.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "VALUE = 000000";
t.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();
```

The `ToTable()` method is used to access the results of the filtered table.

You can explore the expressions you can use with RowFilter in this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: The hardest part for me is figuring out the 2nd part of the OR statement in the correct syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use DISTINCT keyword with the RowFilter expression.

Here you can have some ideas from previous questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602836/select-distinct-in-dataviews-rowfilter